# Need help modeling a complex ring

Tags: modeling

I have a ring which I am trying to model, but it looks very confusing[image: This is it.]
I tried multiple things, but I just can't get it right. I tried adding in two loop cuts to a subsurfed cube and extruding the bottom corners to match the shape of the objects in the center of the band. Then I added a curve and array modifier to have the object follow a circular path so it looked more accurate. All was good, until I had to do the edges of the ring. I am having a lot of touble modeling this part. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, please [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/167467/edit) your question and add more descriptive information showing what you have tried that hasn't worked, and what *specifically* isn't working for you. What do you have so far? Please see [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [here](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/608/how-do-i-ask-a-question-that-is-hard-to-describe) and [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour) for some pointers on how to ask well received questions.

Comment: This ring looks a lot like a car tire ; you will full plenty of tutorials about tires.

Comment: Thank you for the response thibsert, I'll be sure to look it up.